# Calculate percentage of checked checkbox after press a button and show percentage in another activity (android)

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have a problem towards of calculating percentage of checked checkbox. 
My situation is, i have list of checkbox. after user press any checkbox, user should press calculate button. this calculate button will show another activity and also display percentage of checked checkbox. Can anyone help me?

```
percentage = (checked/total checkbox)*100
```

Comment: Check this link. It will solve your problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070082/how-would-i-calculate-percentage-of-checkboxes-clicked

Comment: i already try it, but the app  stopped when click calculate button.. :

Comment: can you please provide logcat for the same

Comment: at com.example.sze.mutabaah.ChecklistActivity.percentageChecked(ChecklistActivity.java:170)
            at com.example.sze.mutabaah.ChecklistActivity$1.onClick(ChecklistActivity.java:62)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)

Comment: cont:


 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: hi, i cannot give all of the logcat because its too long. i will post it half by half

Comment: 09-18 15:10:22.509  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
09-18 15:10:22.509  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 410: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I

Comment: 09-18 15:10:22.509  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-18 15:10:22.509  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
09-18 15:10:22.509  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 432: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I

Comment: 09-18 15:10:22.509  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-18 15:10:22.589  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 189K, 2% free 12116K/12344K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
09-18 15:10:22.599  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 17.361MB for 5760016-byte allocation
09-18 15:10:22.609  31129-31138/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 2% free 17735K/17972K, paused 3ms, total 3ms

Comment: 09-18 15:10:22.759  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
09-18 15:10:22.769  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
09-18 15:10:22.769  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
09-18 15:10:22.769  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
09-18 15:10:22.769  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
09-18 15:10:22.779  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 52

Comment: 09-18 15:10:22.799  31129-31129/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-18 15:12:22.589  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
09-18 15:12:22.589  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 410: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I

Comment: 09-18 15:12:22.589  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-18 15:12:22.589  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
09-18 15:12:22.589  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 432: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
09-18 15:12:22.589  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002

Comment: 09-18 15:12:22.739  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 168K, 2% free 12115K/12324K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
09-18 15:12:22.749  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 17.360MB for 5760016-byte allocation
09-18 15:12:22.759  31757-31766/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 2% free 17735K/17952K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
09-18 15:12:22.929  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46

Comment: 09-18 15:12:22.939  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
09-18 15:12:22.939  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
09-18 15:12:22.939  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
09-18 15:12:22.939  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
09-18 15:12:22.949  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 52
09-18 15:12:22.969  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0

Comment: 09-18 15:12:43.769  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-18 15:12:43.769  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430f3140)
09-18 15:12:43.779  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sze.mutabaah, PID: 31757
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.sze.mutabaah.ChecklistActivity.percentageChecked(ChecklistActivity.java:170)

Comment: at com.example.sze.mutabaah.ChecklistActivity$1.onClick(ChecklistActivity.java:62)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: 09-18 15:13:17.779  31757-31757/com.example.sze.mutabaah I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 31757 SIG: 9
09-18 15:13:17.889  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-18 15:13:17.889  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ Try to disable coredump for pid 31914
09-18 15:13:17.889  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ Process 31914 nice name: com.example.sze.mutabaah

Comment: 09-18 15:13:17.889  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ Extra Options: not specified
09-18 15:13:17.989  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
09-18 15:13:17.989  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 410: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I

Comment: 09-18 15:13:17.989  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-18 15:13:17.989  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
09-18 15:13:17.989  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 432: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
09-18 15:13:17.989  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002

Comment: 09-18 15:13:18.079  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 193K, 2% free 12116K/12348K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
09-18 15:13:18.089  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 17.361MB for 5760016-byte allocation
09-18 15:13:18.089  31914-31923/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 2% free 17735K/17976K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
09-18 15:13:18.239  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46

Comment: 09-18 15:13:18.239  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
09-18 15:13:18.239  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
09-18 15:13:18.249  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
09-18 15:13:18.249  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
09-18 15:13:18.249  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 52

Comment: 09-18 15:13:18.279  31914-31914/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-18 15:13:27.839  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
09-18 15:13:27.839  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 410: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I

Comment: 09-18 15:13:27.839  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-18 15:13:27.839  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
09-18 15:13:27.839  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 432: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I

Comment: 09-18 15:13:27.839  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-18 15:13:27.929  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 197K, 2% free 12115K/12352K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
09-18 15:13:27.939  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 17.360MB for 5760016-byte allocation

Comment: 09-18 15:13:27.949  31958-31967/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 2% free 17735K/17980K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
09-18 15:13:28.129  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
09-18 15:13:28.149  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
09-18 15:13:28.149  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
09-18 15:13:28.149  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50

Comment: 09-18 15:13:28.149  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
09-18 15:13:28.159  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 52
09-18 15:13:28.169  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-18 15:13:48.309  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-18 15:13:48.309  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430f3140)

Comment: 09-18 15:13:48.319  31958-31958/com.example.sze.mutabaah E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sze.mutabaah, PID: 31958
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.sze.mutabaah.ChecklistActivity.percentageChecked(ChecklistActivity.java:170)
            at com.example.sze.mutabaah.ChecklistActivity$1.onClick(ChecklistActivity.java:62)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)

Comment: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit

Comment: $MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: ----------------------------------------

Comment: you can edit your answer instead of commenting this much code

Answer (score 0):

In Activity1,

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity2.class);
i.putExtra("key", chkbox1.getText()); //pass chkbox1 value to another activity
startActivity(i);
```

In Activity2,

```
String chkbox1=getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
```

Comment: how about calculation kris ho?