# how can I get all object in the android view and have access to their id and value?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a main activity and it shows (with setContentView) different xml layout based on user action so main activity does not know witch layout is set and cannot access them by findbyid.

The task of my main activity is just **read all objects in xml file** like TextView, button,... and **save the id and value of them in a hash table** to use in the different class in application framework. The class in the framework knows those objects and can work with them.

the question is how can I get all object in the view and have access to their id and value?

Comment: Do you have a View instance of your layout to get all the ids in it? Or do you only have the layout id?

Comment: I have layout id. but I think I can get a view instance with this code:         setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity_1.this); 
        View theInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_1, null);  haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Is not clear what you want to achieve. Can you post some code?
Btw, this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872238/enumerate-iterate-all-views-in-activity

Comment: `setContentView` must be set only once per activity. If you want more than one view at same activity, use fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Never tested but here is a simple implementation. You can use it using

```
List<Integer> ids = new ViewIdEnumerator(yourView).getIds();
```

Here is the implementation of ViewIdEnumerator.

```
package mobi.sherif.so;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ViewIdEnumerator {
    List<Integer> ids;
    public ViewIdEnumerator(View v) {
        ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        enumerate(v);
    }

    public List<Integer> getIds() {
        return ids;
    }
    private void enumerate(View child) {
        if (child == null)
            return;

        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            enumerate((ViewGroup) child);
        }
        else if (child != null) {
            ids.add(child.getId());
        }
    }

    private void enumerate(ViewGroup parent) {
        ids.add(parent.getId());
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                enumerate((ViewGroup) child);
            } else {
                enumerate(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```