# Close reward video ad in Android

Tags: android, video, viewgroup

I am designing an app that includes a rewarded video before giving the player another life. For user experience and engagement, I want to ensure that this rewarded video is closed after 30 seconds and the user is taken back to the app. We are using a client-side mediation solution for 4 of the largest video networks (Chartboost, Vungle, App Lovin, and Ad Colony).

Many ad networks provide this close functionality, such as MoPub's `MoPubView.destroy()`. However, not all networks provide a programmatic method to close their ads.

All the ad networks I've come across extend the `View` class to show their ads. This means that the ad itself must be in the app's `View` stack.

Is there a way to cycle through `Views` and close the one that matches an ad? It seems this should be possible, since MoPub's SDK uses the following code:

```
public void destroy() {
    unregisterScreenStateBroadcastReceiver();
    removeAllViews();
    ....
}
```

And `removeAllViews()` is a [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) method composed of:

```
public void removeAllViews() {
    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    requestLayout();
    invalidate(true);
}
```

I'm stumped with combining this `ViewGroup` code with a `View` iterator like in [Enumerate/Iterate all Views in Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872238/enumerate-iterate-all-views-in-activity). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ad view is spawned by your app why don't you keep a reference to the spawned view and close that one after 30 seconds? Or if they supply XML configuration, give the XML view an ID and do a findViewById(...) and close that view.